# EditText Cursor positioning Issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using below function to forcefully making the first letter of each word to Capital letter in Edittext.

```
 public String capitalizeFirstLetterWord(String s) {
    StringBuilder cap = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        try {
            char x = s.charAt(i);
            if (x == ' ') {
                cap.append(" ");
                char y = s.charAt(i + 1);
                cap.append(Character.toUpperCase(y));
                i++;
            } else {
                cap.append(x);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {

        }
    }
    //finally, capitalize the first letter of the sentence
    String sentence = cap.toString();
    if (sentence.length() > 0) {
        sentence = String.valueOf(sentence.charAt(0)).toUpperCase(); //capitalize first letter

        if (cap.toString().length() > 1) { //check if there's succeeding letters
            sentence += cap.toString().substring(1); //append it also
        }
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

and calling it in afterTextChange() method as below :

```
  @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (getActivity().getCurrentFocus() == mEdtName) {
            if (editable.toString().length() > 0 &&
                    !editable.toString().equals(mOldName)) {
                mOldName = editable.toString(); //prevent infinite loop
             mEdtName.setText(capitalizeFirstLetterWord(editable.toString()));
mEdName.setSelection(mEdGymName.getText().length()); //set the cursor to the end of the editText
            }
        }
    }
```

But, the issue is when I trying to erase a character from the middle of the Whole string in Editext. The Cursor is moving at the end of the Text.
.
It's because of the below line in **afterTextChanged()** method.
If I comment that line, Cursor moves to the first position.
.

What might be the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (getActivity().getCurrentFocus() == mEdtName) {
        if (editable.toString().length() > 0 && !editable.toString().equals(mOldName)) {

            int selection = mEditName.getSelectionEnd();

            mOldName = editable.toString(); //prevent infinite loop
            mEditName.removeTextChangedListener(this);
       mEditName.setText(capitalizeFirstLetterWord(editable.toString()));
            mEditName.setSelection(selection);
            mEditName.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you just added  mEditName.addTextChangedListener(this); ??? no changes in output...  :(

Comment: @JaiminModi no, look at the 6th line mEditName.removeTextChangedListener(this);

Comment: Sir, still new issue comes. Its working. But, after erasing a letter when I press SPACE, it erases my whole word..! :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use InputFilter to do that.